# Can't install MATE 1.20 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, mate

```
ryan@Dell-Latitude-E6330:~$ sudo apt-get install mate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mate-desktop-environment' instead of 'mate'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mate-desktop-environment : Depends: mate-desktop-environment-core (= 1.20.0+2~16.04.york0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: atril (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: engrampa (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: eom (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: mate-calc (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: mate-applets (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: mate-icon-theme-faenza (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: mate-media (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: mate-notification-daemon (>= 1.20) but 1.18.1-1~16.04.york0 is to be installed
                            Recommends: mate-power-manager (>= 1.20) but 1.18.1-3~16.04.york2 is to be installed
                            Recommends: mate-screensaver (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: mate-system-monitor (>= 1.20) but 1.18.1-2~16.04.york0 is to be installed
                            Recommends: mate-utils (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: pluma (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there any way I can install Ubuntu MATE correctly?

Comment: I think you should use `mate-desktop-environment ` package from official [MATE for Xenial PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/xenial-mate), but it provides only 1.16.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at some of the messages.

```
Note, selecting 'mate-desktop-environment' instead of 'mate'
```

`apt-get` is replacing the package name `mate` with `mate-desktop-environment`. Instead of assuming the package is called `mate`, you could have looked at `apt-cache search mate`.

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mate-desktop-environment : Depends: mate-desktop-environment-core (= 1.20.0+2~16.04.york0) but it is not going to be installed
```

This says that the package you asked to install (`mate-desktop-environment`, was `mate`) depends on a package called `mate-desktop-environment-core`. "Depends", in this context means "gotta have it, won't work without it".

To fix just this problem, do:

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment mate-desktop-environment-core
```

However, all the `Recommends:` lines recommend other packages that make `mate` more useful. You could simply add the packages you want to the command line. My `apt-cache search mate | grep -w mate | wc -l` shows `120` packages with `mate` in their names. Investigate them. Start with `apt-cache search mate | grep -w mate`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but its still doing the same thing is this because i have mate 1.18 installed or is it because the ppa's i have. ryan@Dell-Latitude-E6330:~$ sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment mate-desktop-environment-core
[sudo] password for ryan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of incomeing

Comment: Depends: mate-session-manager (>= 1.20) but 1.18.2-1~16.04.york0 is to be installed
                                 Depends: mate-settings-daemon (>= 1.20) but 1.18.2-1~16.04.york0 is to be installed
                                 Depends: mate-terminal (>= 1.2

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to install the packages using the `ppa:jonathonf/mate-1.20` or `ppa:jonathonf/mate-1.20-gtk3.22` repositories.

I found the root cause of the above errors to be that only older versions of GTK were available.

I found that running the commands added all the necessary packages to allow a full install of the mate desktop environment.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/mate-1.20-gtk3.22
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gtk3.22
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mate-desktop-environment
```